# Invalid URL not detected in Regex pattern

Tags: javascript, validation, url

I am working on my web development project where I encountered this error. The regex pattern below here is what I am using for my project. Also there is a list of invalid URLs that it cannot check in.

```
(https?://)?([\\da-z.-]+)\\.([a-z.]{2,6})[/\\w .-=?@$&!\-\/#/()]/?
```

Invalid URL:

```
    http://a.b-c.de
    http://a.b-.co
    http://a.b--c.de/
    http://-error-.invalid/
    http:://www.com
    www.com
    W.ww.example.net
    www.example
```

I'm not able to invalidate the above list of URL. Can anyone help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: You should check out https://regex101.com/ They have a helpful regex building experience.

Comment: Why do you think that those URLs are invalid?

Comment: My new Regex pattern after checking through regex101.com and other sites

(https?://(?!www|(?:www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9].[^\\s]{2,}|
www.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9].[^\\s]{2,}|https?://(?!([\w-]+\.)|(?:www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[^\\s]{2,}|www.[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[^\\s]{2,})

I fixed the previous error with the URLs and have few more URLs to validate now.
Valid URL - PASS
Example.com, https://www.example.com, www.example.com,Http://example.com
Invalid URL - FAIL
www.example
Please correct my regex so that both my valid and invalid URL should work